# jquery replace select options with values associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the options of select2 based on the choice in select1. Therefore I made a associative array like this:

```
var rubrieken = {'1': '<option value="10">Rubriek 10</option><option value="20">Rubriek 20</option>','2': '<option value="30">Rubriek 30</option><option value="40">Rubriek 40</option>'};
```

So if in select1 option 2 is selected, the current values of select2 have to be replaced with the options with key 2. Im made the Jquery below, but how to extract the options from the array an put them in the select?

```
var rubrieken = {'1': '<option value="10">Rubriek 10</option><option value="20">Rubriek 20</option>','2': '<option value="30">Rubriek 30</option><option value="40">Rubriek 40</option>'};
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Bij keuze categorie de rubrieken vullen 
    $("#select1").change(function(){
        //maak de huidige select leeg
        $('#select2').empty();
        //selectie uit array van juiste waarden
        $newoptions = "<option>NewO1</option><option>NewO1</option>";
        //vul de select rubriek op basis van categorie keuze    
        $('select#select2').html($newoptions);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: and what are values in select1 `options` . is it 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Would comment your html also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your corresponding option as `key-value` pair. like if option `1` is selected then your access it like  `rubrieken["1"]`

[**Way to access object property.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```
var rubrieken = {'1': '<option value="10">Rubriek 10</option><option value="20">Rubriek 20</option>','2': '<option value="30">Rubriek 30</option><option value="40">Rubriek 40</option>'};
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        //Bij keuze categorie de rubrieken vullen 
        $("#select1").change(function(){
            //maak de huidige select leeg
            $('#select2').empty();
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            if(selectedValue){
                var getOptions = rubrieken[selectedValue];
                $('select#select2').html(getOptions);
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar : Glad it help you. Accept it as answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Please try this!**

```
var rubrieken = {
    '1': '<option value="10">Rubriek 10</option><option value="20">Rubriek 20</option>',
    '2': '<option value="30">Rubriek 30</option><option value="40">Rubriek 40</option>'
};

$(function() {
    $("#select1").change(function() {
        var key = $(this).val();
        var newoptions = rubrieken[key];
        $('#select2').html(newoptions);
    }); 
});
```

> **Note:**
>
> You won't need `$('#select2').empty();` because `.html()` will replace the content.

Good luck!

Comment: Why not use numbers in the array?

Comment: javascript `object` type have slightly different purpose with normal `array`, `object`'s key usually to be a string/name. but if you want just normal array, you can define as simple: `var rubrieken = ['<option value="10">Rubriek 10</option><option value="20">Rubriek 20</option>','<option value="30">Rubriek 30</option><option value="40">Rubriek 40</option>'];` but it'll index from 0.

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar but don't worry, even if you define `rubrieken` as `object` like your code, you can read it with normal array reading `rubrieken[2];` but `not rubrieken.2;` (as usually object read is using dot e.g. `rubrieken.opt2;`)